# Can a Garmin Touring charging port be repaired

Tags: garmin

The charging port on my Garmin Touring has become wobbly and will no longer charge. It is about 3 years old.

Looking around on line it appears the solder may have weakened and the charging port has disconnected from the circuit board.

What I haven't been able to find is if this is a repairable issue, either at home, via Garmin or somewhere else.

Does anyone know if this is possible to repair or do I need to start saving for a new one?

Comment: This is more of an electronics question than a bicycles question. But your best bet is to find someone who knows electronics in your area. Depending on the board, re soldering the connector on will likely require a hot air gun and some solder paste at the minimum.

Comment: Are you willing to open it up and post pictures of the connector area? I use solder in wire form and a fine tip iron (cheap 15W) for most connectors.  [An old answer of mine at SU](http://superuser.com/a/799225/245275) might be of interest, along with the rest of that thread.

Comment: Take it to a local computer repairman.  Not the guys at Best Buy, but an independent shop.  Or perhaps an independent cellphone repair guy.

Comment: A cell phone repair guy would likely be a better bet since this used to happen a lot more on cellphones fairly recently. I don't think most computer repair guys would have soldered anything in 10-15 years+, even at an independent shop.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Garmin about it directly? The bayonet bits on my Edge 500 unit snapped off after I'd had it for several years, I emailed Garmin to ask if I could buy a new case and they replaced it with a reconditioned unit free of charge. Its worth a try - if you don't ask you don't get.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the unit is not fully sealed and the port is accessible then yes, the port can be changed. Changing the port is not a job just anybody can do, as in a lot of cases these days just like with mobile phone repairs experience in micro-soldering may be required especially where the ports contacts are soldered to the PCB.

Hot air stations are normally used on this sort of job as the port is usually soldered to a PCB ground plane which makes removal with an iron alone virtually impossible.

A mobile phone repair specialist will likely be able to replace the port for you.